# Parameters for which a quadratic matrix equation has a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, roots, quadratics, matrix-equations

Let function $f : \Bbb R^{n \times n} \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$f(X) := a^TXb+c^TXEXd$$

where $a, b, c, d \in \Bbb R^n$ and $n \times n$ matrix $E$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite.

Under what conditions on $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $E$ is there a unique matrix $X$ such that $f(X)=0$?

This cannot always be true, of course. For instance, if $a=b=c=d=0$ then any matrix $X$ will satisfy $f(X)=0$.

Comment: Think of the $1 \times 1$ case: for what values of $a,b,c$ does $a x^2 + b x + c = 0$ have a unique solution? Are you looking for something similar for matrices?

Comment: Yes I am. Following on your hint I'm guessing that we would need to write $f(X)$ as $e'(X-F)^2g$ for it to have a unique solution. That helps. Thanks.

Comment: But the $0$-th order term is missing in $f$.

Comment: In the $1\times 1$ case, we need $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=0$ for a unique solution. Our $c$ term here is 0 so this would imply that I need the $b$ term to be 0. So by analogy I would say that I need either $a$ or $b$ in $f$ to be 0. But that's probably not the whole story. If $c=d=0$ then $f$ is a linear equation and it could also have a unique solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n=1$, $a^TXb+c^TXEXd=0$ has only the trivial solution if and only if exactly one of $ab$ and $cdE$ is zero.

When $n=2$, the solutions to $a^TXb+c^TXEXd=0$ are never unique. In fact, one can always pick two nonzero vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $a^Tu=v^Td=0$. Then $X=uv^T$ is a non-trivial solution.